# How to show the filenames in a folder using batch script

Tags: batch-file

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do echo %%~na >> fileslist.txt
```

If I run this code in a folder then a .txt file named fileslist will be created and all the filenames of .txt file in that folder is printed in that file. But I want to create two files (suppose `fileslist1` and `fileslist2`) and half of the files of that folder will go to fileslist1 and next half of the file in that folder will go to fileslist2. How can I do that?

Please help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET count=0
FOR /F %%F IN ('dir /b *.txt') DO SET /A count=!count!+1
SET /A half=%count%/2
IF %half%*2 LSS %count% SET /A half=%half%+1
SET index=0
FOR %%a IN (*.txt) DO (
    SET /A index=!index!+1
    IF %half% GEQ !index! ECHO %%~na >> fileslist1.txt
    IF %half% LSS !index! ECHO %%~na >> fileslist2.txt
)
```

A big chunk of the code serves just for identifying what's the "half of the files" as we need a handling for odd numbers. You could skip a big part of the code if you knew how many files there are or if you'd say let's put the first 10 files into list1.txt, the next 10 files into list2.txt, the next 10 into list3.txt and so on. "Half" is quite annoying in this context. Or maybe I just can't think of an elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your intelligence. But I want to divide equally. Suppose there are 32 files. So fileslist1 contains 16, and fileslist2 contains another 16. But in this case one contains 17 and another 15. Will you please help me to divide it equally.

Comment: @DebadritoSaha I've edited my answer. Should work now.

Comment: much quicker counting: `for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.txt ^|find /c /v ""') do @set count=%%f` (on my system with 3678 files: 0,22 sec instead of 2.02 sec)

Comment: @Stephan This is what I've been trying to remember but couldn't! This is obviously way better! THX

Comment: It surely helps. Thanks @MichaelS

Comment: Thanks @Stephan for your help.